# In "_reduce" function i made, spliced array is allocated to original array, but is not changed, why?

Tags: javascript, slice

```
function _each(list, iter){
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        iter(list[i]);
    }
}
```

this is code for list circuit

```
var slice = Array.prototype.slice;
function _rest(list, num){
    return slice.call(list, num || 1);
}
```

I want to apply this to not only array but array-like object. So I use slice.call

```
function _reduce(list, iter, memo){
    if(arguments.length == 2){
        memo = list[0];
        list = _rest(list);
    }
    _each(list, function(val){
        memo = iter(val, memo);
    })
    return memo;
}
```

This is "_reduce" function. If I don't put memo argument, _rest(list) is allocated to list.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

console.log(_reduce(arr, function(a, b){return a + b}));
console.log(arr);
```

10
test.js:79 (4) [1, 2, 3, 4]

This is result and i wonder why arr is not changed? I expect that (3) [2, 3, 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice` returns a copy of the original data with the appropriate slice applied.

When you say `list = _rest(list);`, you're reassigning the local variable `list` to the slice of everything except the first value. You're not modifying the original array, since objects (non-primitives) are passed by reference and you're replacing that reference with another.

If you wanted to modify the original, you would need to use `Array.prototype.shift()`, which removes the first element on the original array, and then you don't need to reassign you'd just call `.shift()` on it.